# How can I set permissions on an RSS file?

Tags: rss

I want to create an in-house RSS feed (I work for 3 Mobile, Australia) for consumption on an INQ1 mobile phone, or any other RSS reader for that matter. However, testing it out on the phone's built-in RSS reader, I realize that without the ability to password protect the feed, or otherwise restrict access to it, I stand little chance of being able to develop this idea further.

One thing I thought of was to periodically change the Uri for the feed, so managers who had left the company couldn't continue to subscribe and see sensitive information, but the idea of making users do that would make it a harder sell, and furthermore is terribly inelegant.

Does anybody know how to make it so that prior to downloading a feed, a reader would have to authenticate the user? Is it part of the metadata within the feed, or something you would set in the reader software?

**Update:** I should have explained that I already have placed folder-level permissions on the parent folder, which brings up the normal authentication dialog when the feed is viewed in a browser, but which just results in a failed update with no explanation or warning in the phone's RSS reader, and is indistiguishable from the file being missing, when I next try and refresh the feed.

Comment: Good question: I have been thinking something on similar lines of late :)

Comment: You should add info about your application stack (ASP.NET, WCF, ASP.NET MVC etc) if you want some more specifics about how you'd go about doing this. Also, are you worried about authenticating consumers, or encrypting the contents, or both?

Comment: It'd be done using C#, but I didn't realise that would be relevant, as I could just as easy create the feed by hand, as some of my team mates would end up doing.
No encryption, just authentication. Need to make sure that managers that are currently employed are the only people to have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reader in the phone doesn't support HTTP Basic or Digest, your best bet is to create a unique url to the feed for each consumer. Have the customer login and generate a link with some token in it that is unique for that user. If the user ever leaves, you can then deny that token, shutting down access.

If you go this route, you probably want to investigate including the [Feed Access Control](http://www.bloglines.com/about/specs/fac-1.0) bits in your feed. It's not perfect, but it is respected by the bigger aggregators, so if one of your clients decides to subscribe to the feed with Reader or Bloglines, things shouldn't show up in search results.

Comment: The unique url solution is the one I had come to myself eventually, so thanks for the support your answer has given me! My team would have to manage a list of consumers/uniqueIDs, each of which would form part of the feed's url. If someone leaves, the ID is removed. I was also thinking of having a weak reciprocal security element: each time the user updates their feed, the first item in the feed could say 'Last viewed 30 minutes ago'. If that doesn't ring true, then something's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would set the permissions on the feed itself, forcing authentication, much like the Twitter feeds. The problem with this is that many readers (including Google Reader) don't yet support authenticated feeds.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have authentication over a secure channel. These posts explain it pretty well:

- [RSS Security](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2005/09/08/rss-security/)
- [Private RSS Feeds](http://labs.silverorange.com/archive/2003/july/privaterss)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your RSS feed is over HTTP then basic HTTP authentication would probably do the trick. This would either be done at the web server level (in IIS for example) or via whatever framework you're using to produce the feed (in ASP.NET for example).

The authentication scheme (basic username/password, NTLM, Kerberos etc) is up to you. If you're using WCF to produce the feed then these decisions are things you can make later and apply via config if needed.

Are you simply looking to authenticate consumers of the feed, or also encrypt it to prevent the information from being read by a "man in the middle". If you require encryption then SSL is probably the easiest to implement.

You should avoid simply "hiding" the RSS feed by changing it's name.

**update:**
Your question (with it's update) sounds like you're actually having issues with the RSS client on the device. You need to determine whether the phones RSS client understands how to deal with basic/digest authentication etc.

Assuming it doesn't, is there anything in the HTTP request that could allow you to associate a device with a user? Is there an HTTP Header that gives you a unique device ID? If so, you might be able to then perform a lookup against this data to perform your own weak-authentication, but you should remember that this sort of authentication could be **easily** spoofed.

Does the device have a client certificate that could be used for mutual SSL? If so, then that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Authentication by the webserver is probably the best solution, however to get round the issues of reader not supporting it (Google has been mentioned and I have issues with Safari) you could implement a simple value-key to append to the URL.

```
I.E.

http://www.mydomain/rss.php?key=value
```

Your system could then "authenticate" the key-value and output the RSS, invalid k-v could get a standard "invalid authenticate" message as single item RSS or return a 40x error.

It not very secure as you could see the k-v in the URL but it's a a trade off. An un-authenticated HTTPS would be slightly more secure.

Comment: But that would still involve people having to change the value (of the key) periodically, to change the "password", which is hard to do in some mobile readers, without having to delete the Feed and totally re-enter the Uri.

Comment: Could you tie it to an IP address or MAC address (or both). Do bare in mind that MAC address spoofing is very easy.